# standard deviation line not in the middle of bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, charts, bar-chart

i'm trying to plot some values with their sd values, but the sd lines are not in the middle of each barplot. do you know how to fix or if there's another way.

Here's an example :

```
# Example data: Values and their standard deviations
values <- c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30)  # Mean values
std_dev <- c(1, 2, 1.5, 3, 2.5)   # Standard deviations
labels <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")  # Labels for each bar

# Create a bar plot with custom labels and error bars
barplot(values, ylim = c(0, max(values) + max(std_dev)), 
        names.arg = labels, xlab = "Groups", ylab = "Values", 
        main = "Example Bar Plot with Error Bars", cex.names = 0.7,
        col = "skyblue", cex.axis = 1)

# Add error bars representing standard deviations
for (i in 1:length(values)) {
  arrows(x0 = i, y0 = values[i] - std_dev[i], 
         x1 = i, y1 = values[i] + std_dev[i], 
         angle = 90, code = 3, length = 0.1)
}
```

[image]

Comment: `barplot` has a `space` argument that defines the space between the bars.  It's default is 0.2.  You need to take that into account.  So a simple solution would be to add `space = 0` to your call to `barplot` and modify your loop so that `x0` and `x1` are set to `i-0.5`.  But @user2554330 has given you a more generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `barplot()` function returns a vector giving the centers of the bars. So use this in your code:

```
# Create a bar plot with custom labels and error bars
centers <- barplot(values, ylim = c(0, max(values) + max(std_dev)), 
        names.arg = labels, xlab = "Groups", ylab = "Values", 
        main = "Example Bar Plot with Error Bars", cex.names = 0.7,
        col = "skyblue", cex.axis = 1)

# Add error bars representing standard deviations
for (i in 1:length(values)) {
  arrows(x0 = centers[i], y0 = values[i] - std_dev[i], 
         x1 = centers[i], y1 = values[i] + std_dev[i], 
         angle = 90, code = 3, length = 0.1)
}
```

[image]